# A bug or a feature in JEE when sending multipart requests to a non existing Servlet?

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, multipartform-data, requestdispatcher

I came across this weird behavior in JEE and I don't know if it is an intended behavior or a bug, and I would like to know more about it if any of you have any knowledge about it, thank you in advance;

## The behavior

When I send a multipart request to a non existing Servlet (i.e. I specify a non existing Servlet URL in the forms' action) I'm unable to retrieve the parameters or the parts, and I just get an empty map for the parameters and an empty collection for the parts

## Setup

I have a main `Filter` in my web application mapped to intercept all request like so:

```
@WebFilter("/*")
public class Filter extends HttpFilter {
```

And two Servlet each mapped like so:

```
@WebServlet("/servA")
@MultipartConfig(
        fileSizeThreshold = 1024 * 1024 * 1,
        maxFileSize = 1024 * 1024 * 10,
        maxRequestSize = 1024 * 1024 * 50
        )
public class ServletA extends HttpServlet {
```

And

```
@WebServlet("/servB")
@MultipartConfig(
        fileSizeThreshold = 1024 * 1024 * 1,
        maxFileSize = 1024 * 1024 * 10,
        maxRequestSize = 1024 * 1024 * 50
        )
public class ServletB extends HttpServlet {
```

The filter receives all the requests and *sends* them to one of the two Servlets, and then the Servlets try to retrieve the parameters and parts of the request

## Tests

I tried multiple stuff to pinpoint the problem exactly and my experiments went like this

### Sending the request trough `chain.doFilter`

In the forms' action I specified, in the first time, the URL for the the first Servlet like so `<form method="post" action="http://localhost:8080/TestBug/servA" enctype="multipart/form-data">` and in the `Filter` I call the `chain.doFilter` method and the process goes as expected, everything works fine and the Servlet is able to retrieve the parameters and parts sent with the form. Same thing for when I specify the second Servlet the second time like so `<form method="post" action="http://localhost:8080/TestBug/servB" enctype="multipart/form-data">`, it works as expected. I also tried specifying a non existing Servlet like so `<form method="post" action="http://localhost:8080/TestBug/foo" enctype="multipart/form-data">` and as expected I get a **404 - Not found** response.
This first test was done just to make sure everything is working fine, and that the `@MultipartConfig` annotations are well set and that everything is mapped correctly

### Sending the request trough `requestDispatcher.forward`

Now here is where the weird behavior occurs, at first I specify `ServletA` in the forms' action and in the `Filter` I call `request.getRequestDispatcher("/servA").forward(request, response);` on the received requests, this works fine. I try the same thing with `ServletB`, changing both the forms' action and the requestDispatcher, also works fine.

Then I specify `ServletA` in the forms' action but in the `Filter` I forward the request to `ServletB`, and everything works fine. `ServletB` is able to retrieve the parameters and the parts. Same thing when i reverse it, now specifying `ServletB` in the forms' action but in the filter I forward it to `ServletA`, it works just fine, `ServletA` is able to retrieve the parameters and parts even though the request was originally made to `ServletB`

**BUT** when I specify a non existing Servlet in the forms' action, for example like so `<form method="post" action="http://localhost:8080/TestBug/foo" enctype="multipart/form-data">` and I forward it in `Filter` to either `ServletA` or `ServletB` they are both unable to retrieve the parameters or the parts and instead they just return an empty map when calling `request.getParameterMap` and an empty collection when calling `request.getParts()`

#### Notes

I tried this on Tomcat V10 and Glassfish V7 and I got the same results, which led me to believe that it is something to do with JEE specifications

That is the behavior I encountered, as I said, I would be thankful for  any informations about it or any leads or direction on where to read more about it, or maybe it's something else completely

#### Quick-**dirty**-fix

I found a makeshift solution to this behavior that works for my case and for the way that made me encounter it in the first place, which is to simply declare another Servlet like so

```
@WebServlet("/*")
@MultipartConfig(
        fileSizeThreshold = 1024 * 1024 * 1,
        maxFileSize = 1024 * 1024 * 10,
        maxRequestSize = 1024 * 1024 * 50
        )
public class ServletM extends HttpServlet {
```

and then forbid making any request to it, and continue using your normal Servlets

#### Source code

Here is the [source code](https://github.com/telos-matter/WeirdBehaviorInJEE) if any one wants to try it out for themselves

Comment: Chances are, there is no third servlet "configured" in web.xml , try putting that into web.xml but I'm reasonably sure the app will throw a loading error for resource not found on application deploy loading (if there is no actual class installed).

Comment: I would guess that the container checks if multipart handling is requested before the filter gets active, so in the cases that work, please check if the request coming into the filter is already prepared as a multipart request, and then if the same is true for the non-working configuration.

Comment: @SamuelMarchant I made sure there is nothing configured in the web.xml file and only used annotations. The web.xml file literally only has the XML version element and the root element <web-app> with its attributes and nothing inside it

Comment: @cyberbrain not sure what you exactly meant by checking the incoming request, I do the same check operations in the filter before sending them to the servlet, and same results in all cases, what ever happens when it gets to the servlet is the same in the Filter.
Here is the source code if any one wants to test it out for them selves https://github.com/telos-matter/WeirdBehaviorInJEE

Comment: There is certainly no third servlet after the container checks, nothing in its annotation list. I wouldn't quite call that a bug but it would understand it is running without the name of that servlet to index parameters to, alike null for the name of the map object (on a map of servlet names). Perhaps get all "servlet names and look for a null keynamed servlet but somehow I don't see that being good practice in software writing.

Comment: ALSO ! In Tomcat , it is NOT J2EE compliant ! E.g. the application (war) is a "ServletContext" object , whereas in J2EE compliant servers, it is an "ApplicationContext".  The commercial TomEE version of tomcat is J2EE compliant.

Comment: @SamuelMarchant but Tomcat supports the Servlet Standard - it's even linked on the documentation homepage.

Comment: @telos In your failing configuration the container (Tomcat) cannot know that the servlet you want to access needs a multipart splitting, as you do not specify the target servlet at configuration time, but just redirect to it at runtime. So you can only access the body via the `InputStream` of the request.

Comment: ..."Tomcat supports the Servlet Standard "... True. You should understand in the filter whether your "parameters" existed, you filled in the form? If something is not "registered" it would be unwise practice to keep it anyhow. I find it valid to have any such problem to not be usable, it goes against all secure principals! In short, no matter the rejection , it is not a bug. Register it validly with the container app and service or it is to be treated as mistake or malware! In any case, you would want the BIND section of the server code to understand it and the Service object and Config.